# How do you refer to grouping numbers in lots of 60?

Tags: time, measuring-units

We have the term "metric" for things measured in decimal or powers of 1000:

- millimeter
- meter
- kilometer

And the term "hexadecimal" for things measured in base 16.

What term describes grouping numbers in powers of sixty, such as used in time or degrees:

- 23:59:59.999
- 179° 59' 59.999"

Comment: Don't forget octal! Everyone forgets octal... :(

Comment: I don't forget octal.  I work with octal daily.  :-)

Comment: Octal is deserving of more publicity, IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Sexagesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal)* is the word:

> Sexagesimal (base 60) is a numeral system with sixty as its base. It originated with the ancient Sumerians in the 3rd millennium BC, it was passed down to the ancient Babylonians, and it is still used — in a modified form — for measuring time, angles, and the geographic coordinates that are angles.